# dict(zip()) function compressing two lists in Python

Tags: dictionary, zip, dictionary-comprehension

These two lists imported from json file and I can't use `dict(zip()` properly.

```
l1 = ['grant_type', 'scope', 'client_id', 'client_id', 'grant_type', 'scope', 'code', 'redirect_uri']

l2 = ['client_credentials', 'AIS', '{{client_id}}', '{{client_id}}', 'authorization_code', '{{scope}}:{{consents_id}}', '{{response}}', '{{redirect_url}}']

lists = dict(zip(l1, l2))

print(lists)
```

Output:

```
{'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'scope': '{{scope}}:{{consents_id}}', 'client_id': '{{client_id}}', 'code': '{{response}}', 'redirect_uri': '{{redirect_url}}'}
```

I guess there is something with double curly brackets "{{ }}", but I didn't find any information about them and how I can solve this problem.

Thank you for the response!

Comment: Why isn't that output valid?  What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Firstly, in a final lists dict there is 5 key, values. And second, they shuffled a little bit

Comment: Nothing is shuffled, and a dictionary can't have duplicate keys, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): "It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique"

Comment: Oh, okay. Now it makes sense. I will try a different path. Thank you for the response!